# Fluid layout of text in Flex3

Tags: apache-flex, user-interface, text, layout, flex3

In my Flex3 app I have some floating windows which contain variable amounts of text. The windows are meant to be user-resizable. Currently, while I can resize the windows OK, I can't get the text in a TextArea in the window to re-flow when the window is resized. I've come across blog postings that there's a size bug in TextArea that means that setting the text content does not re-size the TextArea properly, together with suggested workarounds. In my case, the content stays the same but the geometry of the container changes. What seems to be happening is that the TextArea adopts a fixed size when it is first rendered, and no amount of resizing the container changes that. Can anyone suggest a means of creating a fluid text area in Flex?

Ian

Comment: How are you resizing the windows? Do you use custom code for that? Do you have code that streches the dimensions of the TextArea? If possible, you might want to post some sample code so we can help you find the problem. I just tried resizing a TextArea in an Application and that seems to work OK.

Comment: Please post some of your code. It might help alot to understand what exactly happens in your application. The Flex framework sometimes is a bit to much and it's easy to set some property wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By binding the textArea's width to its container's with, you can manage to keep the margins and borders and don't have to deal with percentages. 
Also, your textArea will be resized each time its parent changes in size. 
i'm thinking of something like this:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import spark.layouts.supportClasses.LayoutBase;

        protected function onButtonClicked(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            currentState = (event.target.selected ? 'largeState' : 'smallState');
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:TitleWindow id="window" width="300" height="200">
    <s:TextArea width="{window.width - 10}" height="{window.height - 60}" 
        text="{IMyConsts.LOREMIPSUM}" borderVisible="false" />
    <s:ToggleButton id="btnEffect" bottom="5"  click="onButtonClicked(event)"
        label="{btnEffect.selected ? 'Go smaller' : 'Go larger'}" />
</s:TitleWindow>
<s:states>
    <s:State name="smallState" />
    <s:State name="largeState" />
</s:states>
<s:transitions>
    <s:Transition fromState="smallState" toState="*">
        <s:Resize target="{window}" widthTo="400" heightTo="300" />
    </s:Transition>
    <s:Transition fromState="largeState" toState="*">
        <s:Resize target="{window}" widthTo="300" heightTo="250" />
    </s:Transition>
</s:transitions>
```

Comment: This seems like a good solution to the problem, so thanks for that. I've actually switched away from using Flex anymore - Javascript and HTML5 for us now! But hopefully your answer will help others with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found a great example of [fluid windows](http://examples.adobe.com/flex3/devnet/dashboard/main.html) please do visit it. They provide source code also so may be you would get better idea.

http://examples.adobe.com/flex3/devnet/dashboard/main.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try Text Layout Framework from Adobe:
http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/textlayout/

Answer (score 0):

I can take a whack at this... but don't laugh..
I am not sure if you need to use a particular container but in any event, set the width and height to 100% and use Grid > GridRow and GridItem to size and resize Text Control you can specify the width of the table or just use it just like an HTML table in Flex to manipulate the size of controls and containers....

hope that helps...